# use uuid on the move option on Camel File route

Tags: apache-camel

how can I use uuid

> `<bean id="uuid" class="org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleUuidGenerator" />`

on the move option on Camel File route ? in order to add a uuid string on the file name when moving it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExchangeId is a UUID, so you can simply reference the '${exchangeId}' from [Simple language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) without having to mess with setting up the bean.

If you really want to use your own Uuid generator, reference the bean name in the parameter:

> ${bean:uuid.generateid}

Where 'uuid' is your bean id and generateid is the method name example here: [File language](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html)